# Pandas, set on a copy of a slice from DataFrame problem

Tags: python, pandas

I've been struggling with a Pandas warning for a while now.

I have this pretty simple piece of code:

```
def get_delta(df): 
    df['delta_current_day'] = df['close'] - df['open']
    df = df[pd.notnull(df['delta_current_day'])]

    df['delta_next_day'] = df['delta_current_day'].shift(-1)

    return df
```

Every time I get this error:

*A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead*

I've read a lot of question about it here on stackoverflow but none works for me. 
I've tried somethings like this:

```
 df.loc[:, 'delta_next_day'] = df['delta_current_day'].shift(-1)

# OR 
list = df['delta_current_day'].tolist()
df.loc[:, 'delta_next_day'] = list[:1]
```

but I still get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what's pd.__version__?

Comment: My current pandas version is: 0.24.2

Comment: your `loc` solution shouldn't produce the warning in 0.25+

Comment: I'm afraid that by upgrading pandas I'll break more +1000 lines of code working

Comment: Are you sure? 0.24 to 0.25 had more method not many changes, you can always suppress the warning with `warning`

Comment: `df = df[pd.notnull(df['delta_current_day'])].copy()`?

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the issue, the first (`df['delta_current_day'] = ...`) or the last (`df['delta_next_day'] = ...`? Try commenting out the last line two lines to see if you still get the error from the first assignment.

Comment: The error is on ```df['delta_next_day'] = df['delta_current_day'].shift(-1)```

Comment: Always share the entire error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.copy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
df = df[pd.notnull(df['delta_current_day'])].copy()
#df = df.loc[pd.notnull(df['delta_current_day'])] #or this
df['delta_next_day'] = df['delta_current_day'].shift(-1)
```

---

**this is a slice:**

```
df = df[pd.notnull(df['delta_current_day'])]
```

> A (`df['delta_current_day'].shift(-1)`) value is trying to be set on a
>   (`df[pd.notnull(df['delta_current_day'])]`)
>   copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Comment: The error is on ```df['delta_next_day'] = df['delta_current_day'].shift(-1)```

Comment: have you tryed it?

Comment: If you could give me the explanation in your answer, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: you have to create a new object, `df[pd.notnull(df['delta_current_day'])]` 
 is not

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this:

```
# Sample data.
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'open': [100, 102, np.nan, 102],
    'close': [101.5, 102.5, np.nan, 104]
})

def get_delta(df):
    df = df.dropna().assign(delta_current_day=df.eval('close - open'))
    return df.assign(delta_next_day=df['delta_current_day'].shift(-1))

>>> get_delta(df)
    open  close  delta_current_day  delta_next_day
0  100.0  101.5                1.5             0.5
1  102.0  102.5                0.5             2.0
3  102.0  104.0                2.0             NaN
```

Of course, this introduces look ahead bias.  Why are you using tomorrow's delta today?